# "Type arguments do not conform to class' type parameter bounds" under specific conditions

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

Given these classes in Scala 2.11.8:

```scala
class A[T] {
  class P[TT >: T]

  def p[TT >: T]: P[TT] = new P[TT]
}
class B[T](val a: A[T]) {
  def p[TT >: T]: a.P[TT] = a.p[TT]
}
class X
class Y extends X
```

The following line produces the compile error `type arguments [Object] do not conform to class P's type parameter bounds [TT >: T]` (even though `X >: Y`):

```scala
val x = new B[Y](new A[Y]).p[X]
```

Interestingly, this error does not appear in the following code:

```scala
new B[Y](new A[Y]).p[X]

val y = new B[Y](new A[Y])
val z = y.p[X]
```

What is the difference that I am not seeing?

I had a hunch that the compiler could not assign a type to `x`, but that now seems strange given that in the following code, `q` is happily assigned `A[Y]#P[X]`:

```scala
val q = new A[Y].p[X]
```

As far as I can tell, `x` should also be assigned `A[Y]#P[X]`.

The REPL gave me what I think is a clue, but I'm not sure how:

```scala
scala> :t new B[Y](new A[Y]).p[Any]
_6.a.P[Any] forSome { val _6: B[Y] }
```

`_6.a.P[Any] forSome { val _6: B[Y] }` is something along the lines of `B[Y]#a.P[Any]` (pseudocode), which seems logically equivalent to `A[Y]#P[Any]`. 
Seems like the fact that the compiler can't turn that into `A[Y]#P[Any]` may be a bug?

My next hunch was that the compiler couldn't turn `new B[Y](new A[Y]).p[Any]` into `A[Y]#P[Any]` because the argument to `B`'s constructor is polymorphic. We could define a class:

```scala
class C[T] extends A[T]
```

and `new B[Y](new C[Y]).p[Any]` would be `C[Y]#P[Any]`. But `A[Y]#P[Any] >: C[Y]#P[Any]`, thus it should be safe for the compiler to assign `new B[Y](...).p[Any]` the type `A[Y]#P[Any]`. Now I'm back to being convinced that this is a compiler bug.

Another interesting detail to note is that the error disappears if the return type of `B.p` is changed to `A[T]#P[TT]`.

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: There are plenty of them: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?q=%22type+arguments%22+%22do+not+conform+to+class%22+%22type+parameter+bounds%22+is%3Aopen
You can open  a ticket.